# my if statement is returning command not found

Tags: shell-script, control-flow

in my script
an if statement
returns:

line 3: []: command not found

the statement:

```
if ["$(pidof -x $(basename $0) -o %PPID)"]; then
    echo process already running; exit;
fi
```

what I tried:

```
if [["$(pidof -x $(basename $0) -o %PPID)"]]; then
    echo process already running; exit;
fi
```

```
if [["$(pidof -x basename $0 -o %PPID)"]]; then
    echo process already running; exit;
fi
```

```
if ["$(pidof -x basename $0 -o %PPID)"]; then
    echo process already running; exit;
fi
```

```
if [[$(pidof -x basename $0 -o %PPID)]]; then
    echo process already running; exit;
fi
```

none seems to work.I get similar error.

line 3: [[]]: command not found

I got the code from here:
https://linuxpip.org/rclone-examples/
https://forum.rclone.org/t/continuous-syncing/12377/2

I did research here:
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression
and looked at the man bash’s Compound Commands section
but they don’t seem to help.

please help
Thank you!

Comment: add at least one space after `[` and `[[` and before `]` and `]]`.

Comment: .. and those required spaces are in the web page cited. Best reference is https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html -- not Google.